# How to add setup and teardown for each test in benchmark.js

Tags: javascript, benchmark.js

I am new to using benchmark.js, the documentation is bit jarring, and not able to find many examples, can anyone please confirm if my code is correct, sorry i cannot share the whole code( company policy).

consider `setText(choice);` as some operation, and I want to compare various choices. (the function works fine independently, i have verified it). Though I am setting setup and teardown function, I am not sure if setting is correct, I want them to run before and after every single run of  `setText(choice);`

using `console.log` , I found that they run only once for every 200 times of `setText(choice);`, I want them running everytime.

also, how do I retrive the ops/sec for each opeartion on completion of suite . You can find the my benchmark suite related code below.

```
var suite = new Benchmark.Suite;
suite.add('innerText', function() {
    setText('innerText');
}, {'setup':setup,'teardown':teardown})
.add('innerHTML', function() {
    setText('innerHTML');
}, {'setup':setup,'teardown':teardown})
.add('textContent', function() {
    setText('textContent');
}, {'setup':setup,'teardown':teardown})
.on('cycle', function(event, bench) {
  log(String(bench));
}).on('complete', function() {
  log('Fastest is ' + JSON.stringify(this));
}).run(false);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am also new to benchmarkjs and hope i can answer correctly.

http://monsur.hossa.in/2012/12/11/benchmarkjs.html

If you read the above article, you will find out the benchmark will go into the analysis and sampling phase.

It will run a number of iterations (i.e. the "test loop") which did setText during sampling phase without calling [`setup`](https://benchmarkjs.com/docs#prototype_setup) or [`teardown`](https://benchmarkjs.com/docs#prototype_teardown).

*So I guess the setup and teardown is just for something you do before entering the test loop and **not exactly for the each test.** You can't get more granular than the test-loop*

You can get *less* granular than the test-loop; you can listen for events on the *entire Benchmark* (vs at the suite-level, or the test-loop level). The second question about each operation on completion of suite, you can get it from on complete event

```
.on('complete', function(event) {
    //will log out the array of benchmark.suite, you can get it from each benchmark suite.
    //e.g event.currentTarget[0].hz which retrieve the operation/s. for the first one.
    console.log(event.currentTarget);
    //equivalent of above; event.currentTarget===this; both are Benchmark.suite.
    console.log(this); 
})
```